# How to exchange a cryptocurrency from an address that's not in a wallet

Tags: ripple, ethereum

Possibly dumb question here (and first-time poster).

I have a Coinbase account with several different cryptocurrencies in it. I recently used ShapeShift to exchange ether (ETH) from my Coinbase wallet to Ripple (XRP).

To do this I generated an XRP address using http://ripplepaperwallet.com. Then, in Coinbase, I sent my ETH to a provisional address generated by ShapeShift, after which they immediately deposited XRP into my generated address.

Here's the question: how do I now spend or use that XRP address? I'm only now realizing it's not hosted by any wallet, so I have no idea how to spend it or exchange it. (I'm trying to get it into the Binance exchange, if possible.) I have both the private key and the address, so in theory I should be able to access the funds, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/
and scroll down to the "Wallets" section on the right side bar.

Download a lightweight wallet of you choice, start the wallet sweep/import the private key, then send to your Binance wallet.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with ToastWallet, as the Minimalist Wallet seemed a little wonky/unintuitive.